# Request_ResourceNotFound calling /v1.0/me

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

The following GET request works, which shows that my AccessToken is valid and that my application has correct permissions to access user information using the Microsoft Graph API:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/
Authorization: Bearer <my_access_token>
```

However, the following GET request does not work and returns the error message:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/
Authorization: Bearer <my_access_token>

{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_ResourceNotFound",
        "message": "Resource '<my_resource_id>' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "<my_request_id>",
            "date": "2018-01-26T06:24:27"
        }
    }
}
```

I am certain that the resource (an "Enterprise Application" object created in my Azure Active Directory B2C instance) **does** exist because I can find it in portal.azure.com and because the first GET request used that same resource and returned successfully.

**My question is: Why can't I access "me" but I can access a list of users?**

Both of the GET requests above are run after I have successfully authenticated into my ASP.NET version 4.71 MVC. Could it be an issue with the way I am saving the authenticated user's information in a cookie? Here is the code for this:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
    private static string appKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientSecret"];
    private static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
    private static string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TenantId"];
    private static string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];

    public static readonly string Authority = aadInstance + tenantId;

    // This is the resource ID of the AAD Graph API.  We'll need this to request a token to call the Graph API.
    string graphResourceId = "https://graph.windows.net";

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = Authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,

                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                {
                    // If there is a code in the OpenID Connect response, redeem it for an access token and refresh token, and store those away.
                   AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) => 
                   {
                       var code = context.Code;
                       ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
                       string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                       AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority, new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));
                       AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                       code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, graphResourceId);

                       string token = result.AccessToken;

                       return Task.FromResult(0);
                   }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

What have I done incorrectly? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your resource URI is wrong.

```
// This is the resource ID of the AAD Graph API.  We'll need this to request a token to call the Graph API.
string graphResourceId = "https://graph.windows.net";
```

should be:

```
string graphResourceId = "https://graph.microsoft.com";
```

As the comment says, that is for AAD Graph API, which is not Microsoft Graph API.

Make sure you also grant permissions to Microsoft Graph API in your app registration.

Comment: Thank you. That was definitely a bug. However, I am still not able to get a successful response from the call `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/`, and I am still getting the "Request_ResourceNotFound" error. I have granted permissions to Microsoft Graph API; if the permissions were not granted, I would instead be seeing an "Insufficient privileges to complete this operation" error. What else could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Hmm, have you checked the access token contains the necessary claims for sure? You can check at e.g. https://jwt.ms

Comment: And also check the token contains the user's info

Comment: Cool, I had never used that before. My access token has the following fields: aud, iss, iat, nbf, exp, aio, app_displayname, appid, appidacr, e_exp, idp, oid, sub, tid, uti, ver. It looks like this token doesn't contain information about the logged-in user or any application roles. Should it?

Comment: Also, when I navigate to the registered application's page on the portal, I see that the "Permissions" item on the scroll blade is greyed out. Do you know why it is greyed out?

Comment: Actually oid is the user's object id. So the info is there. But the problem is it does not contain the necessary scp or roles claim. So, try granting the permissions again in the Azure portal if you can. You should be able to get there via Azure Active Directory -> App Registrations -> your app -> Required permissions. Press Grant Permissions there.

Comment: I have been working on the issue of the greyed out "Permissions" item on the scroll blade. In order to get around this, I re-registered the web application in the Azure portal and am free to set permissions again. What permission needs to be enabled in order to view the "Me" user? Is it a delegated or application permission?

Comment: Thank you so much. You have been really helpful. I can get information about the current user now!